# Adding Toolbar to Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios

Sup fellas, so I have a navigation controller with a table view to which I am trying to add a tool bar, however, the way I have implemented it causes the very last row in the table to be hidden behind the tool bar. I will try to illustrate via pictures:

Table view scrolled to the bottom without tool bar:

[image]

Table view scrolled to the bottom with tool bar(notice how the last "Vendor" row is concealed behind the tool bar):

[image]

I was following [this](http://www.eduoliveros.com/2009/02/navigation-controller-with-toolbar.html) guide and this is what I ended up doing for my implementation:

[image]

As you can see I have a "View" instead of "Window" to work with. Here is the code I have for displaying the tool bar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 [self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
 [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
 [self.navigationController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
}
```

It seems to me that I need to adjust the frame of the navigation controller frame to compensate for the tool bar being at the bottom. This is where I am stuck. How would I go about doing this? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the toolbar to the navigation controller, it will automatically resize itself. Just check this box in IB.

[image: Check "Shows Toolbar" box in IB]

Comment: I was looking for something like this. Sadly, I didn't end up looking in the navigation controller, but instead was focused on view options. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar issue before.

You need to adjust the height of your `UINavigationController`'s view to be exactly 44 pixels *less*.

This should do it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
   [self.navigationController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.x, self.view.frame.y, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 44.0f)];
   [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
}
```

Comment: Good answer man, this is what I had in mind, but the other answer is a much simpler, easier solution, so I chose that answer over yours. Thanks for the response nonetheless!

Comment: @Stunner No problem. Happens to be that the app that I implemented this solution in needed to be completely in code - no IB.